Guy loses a lot of money, turns to drugs and crime
I'm desperately trying to find a movie I watched years ago. Please help me, it's been bugging me for weeks. Movie about a guy who had a lot of money, but his life changed, he did drugs, and in the end he robbed a jewelry store with some other guys (there were like two storylines, which I recall to be very different, somewhat opposite)
The two storylines were really like two different outcomes, in one he had a lot of money and was successful and in the other he had little money and did drugs. I think the movie was released in the early 2000´s but I´m not really sure, it was recorded in a big city in USA (maybe New York, or something). What is the name of this movie?

Year of release? Theatrical or TV movie? Any idea of movie setting/location? Other details?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trading_Places Just putting it out there...

thanks, but it´s not trading places....

It think the movie was released in the early 2000´s but I´m not really sure, it was recorded in a big city in USA (maybe New York, or something)....

Could it be Before the Devil Knows You're Dead?

thanks, but no, that's not it....

I think I know this. Was the plot all weird and sci-fi?

maybe, i don't really remember.... what do you think it is?

You might be looking for Undermind. It's from 2003, set in NYC and is about a wealthy young lawyer called Derrick and a young small-time drug dealer called Zane who suddenly switch lives one morning. We then get to see their parallel stories and how they deal with their new surroundings. Zane also robs a jewelry store. Here's the trailer:




Yeah, that's the one!!! Thanks mate!
